# Scrollable Ionic 4 tabs

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic 4 and want to design scrollable tabs in Ionic4.
But when I add multiple tabs as shown below code, they shrink and are seen on the same view space.

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="top">
    <ion-tab-button tab="account">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label1</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="contact">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label2</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label3</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="account">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label1</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="contact">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label2</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label3</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="account">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label1</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="contact">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label2</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label3</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tab-bar>
```

This is how above code looks like

[image]

Please help.

Comment: These tabs are dong what they're designed to do. You'd have to hack the CSS yourself to do this, in which case you're better off just using icon buttons and a scrollable area.

Comment: thanks @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane tried using custom css and here is my solution.

Solved by using `display: flex` and `overflox-x: scroll`

This is my SCSS file:

```
.segment-card {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    .segment-item {
        display: inline-block !important;
        min-width: 100px !important;
        width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

This is my HTML file:

```
<ion-card no-padding no-margin class="no-border-radius segment-card">
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="account">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label1</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="contact">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label2</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="settings">
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label3</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="account">...
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="contact">...
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="settings">...
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="account">...
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="contact">...
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button class="segment-item" tab="settings">...
    </ion-tab-button>
</ion-card>
```

These are some screen shots
[image]

Screen Shot while scrolling
[image]

Answer (score 1):

SCSS

```
ion-tab-bar {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

works

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use ionic segments for this kind of approach. And there are greate example in docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment

```
<!-- Segment in a toolbar -->
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
    <ion-segment-button value="camera">
      <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="bookmark">
      <ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: Would you be able to add an example of how to achieve the same nested routing/navigation behavior `ion-tabs` provides with `ion-segment`s? The snippet in your answer doesn't have and `routerLink`s or `router-outlets`, so it's not demonstrating a large part of the functionality `ion-tabs` provides.